# Background show clearly and after the content appears blurry.

Tags: background

I'm trying to do a background that at first it looks clearly and after the content appears, I want it to be blurry.  I want this to be in a  CSS with Javascript, not flash. As an a example : http://www.lanvin.com (example is flash). This is possible ? and how ? Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a background in `css` then when the all content loads use `javascript` to place a translucent but bury image over the top.